# Timepicker crashes on applying style

Tags: android

I applied the below style for timepicker:

```
<style name="MyHoloTimePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:textColor">#2eb135</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

I have set the above style to time picker in xml as follows:

```
 <TimePicker 

                android:id="@+id/pickertime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/MyHoloTimePicker"
                />
```

I got the below exception:

```
12-03 01:12:26.742: E/AndroidRuntime(9279): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException <br>
12-03 01:12:26.742: E/AndroidRuntime(9279): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

How can I sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker.  Try setting the parent to:

```
parent="@android:style/Widget.DatePicker"
```

EDIT:

I found that the DeviceDefault themes are in a different file and can by used by API 14+.

[themes_device_defaults.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes_device_defaults.xml)

Comment: I edited my response.  I was wrong, because I looked at the default themes.xml file and missed that they put the newer themes in another file.  Post the code you use.  Maybe you are not referencing it correctly with the findViewById() command.